# Objective-c linking error with duplicate-symbol error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I know there are questions on here similar to this, but I have not been able to sort it out.

I have a view that has this in the .m above the implementation

```
CFDataRef CopyImagePixels(CGImageRef inImage){
    return CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(inImage));
}
```

Everything works fine, but I have another view that needs to access that same function, if I put it in /that/ views .m file, same location.. the compiler throws a duplicate symbol error..

The only file these two have in common that they include is:

```
#import "MopalAppDelegate.h"
```

I thought maybe putting the code in the AppDelegate, but that throws the same error when I attempt to build..

I am still quite new to obj-c, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: The error:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _CopyImagePixels in  /Users/critter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mopal-dtgtjbahdowmuderbstlmsiznwsi/Build/Intermediates/Mopal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mopal.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewerController.o and /Users/critter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mopal-dtgtjbahdowmuderbstlmsiznwsi/Build/Intermediates/Mopal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mopal.build/Objects-normal/i386/StudyListDetailController.o for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Xcode4/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is being declared and defined in the global scope.  When you place the same function definition in two different `.m` files, you end up with two different functions (as far as the compiler is concerned) that have the same name in the same scope (global), leaving it with no way of knowing which one you intend to call when you say `CopyImagePixels(myImage);`.  Hence the error message.

So there are a couple of options.  One is to define your function as a private member function on the objects that use it, like:

```
@implementation MyClass

- (CFDataRef) copyImagePixels: (CGImageRef)inImage {
    return CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(inImage));
}

@end
```

The other (and less preferred) option is to move your function *declaration* to a shared header file, like `MopalAppDelegate.h`, and its *implementation* into your `MopalAppDelegate.m` file.  This creates a function declaration that can be shared out to other classes, with a single definition in the `.m` file.

Comment: see.. I didn't even know there /was/ a global scope. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

You want to put the function definition in a header that the two files share, implement it in the corresponding .m file, and import that header into both views.

But if that's all the function does, why not just call `CGDataProviderCopyData` directly in both places?

Comment: Aye. that makes sense.  And it just never occurred to me to call it directly... it's been one of those days..  Thanks

Comment: You should put the function *declaration* in a header that the two files share. That definition should go in only one place.

Comment: Yeah, I guess declaration is the proper term. I usually call them definition and implementation.